# How to build windows 32 bit exe file through Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-windows

I am a Flutter developer. I have build one windows 64-bit exe file. It's working perfectly in 64-bit windows OS but is it possible to build a 32-bit exe file through Flutter? Please assist me. Thank you.

Comment: No, Flutter does not support 32-bit Windows as a target. https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/37777

Comment: through any dart package, can we do it?

Answer (score 1):

because it does not support 32bit Windows

Comment: through any dart package, can we do it?

Comment: http://47.240.41.80/packages/win32/versions/1.6.2

Comment: @AnmolMishra I think  - https://pub.dev/packages/win32 , 
dart package is for running flutter in windows 32 not for building windows 32-bit exe file.